# Am I assigning to the same variable or redefining a new variable?

Tags: c++

In A.h:

```
#ifndef A_h
#define A_h

#include "string"

extern std::string a;

#endif
```

In A.cpp, in the global scope:

```
#include "A.h"

std::string a = "a";
```

Comment: If I recall, you shouldn't be using `extern` in `A.cpp`. Just use `std::string a = "a";`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4268620/613130 AND *look at the warnings of your compiler*.

Comment: @Dave - that's a matter of good style. Even with the `extern`, since there is an initializer, it's a definition.

Comment: @PeteBecker OK, well I guess my comment is still technically correct — the best kind of correct.

Comment: @Dave - agreed. Sorry I wasn't more clear.

Comment: @PeteBecker perfectly clear. I was just being silly; it's a quote.

Comment: @Dave - I see. Found it. It's a good line.

Comment: You guys sound like best friends =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not redefining a variable, because your code has only one definition - the one in the CPP file. The one in the header is a declaration, because it uses an `extern` keyword. The CPP file provides a definition to the variable declared in the header.

Comment: I'm unclear about why you need to declare the type of the variable in the global scope where as you would only need to declare a variable's name to assign to it in a function, can you enlighten me?

Comment: @Hobbyist Without the type the variable would not be usable outside of the CPP file where the variable is defined: compiler needs to know the type of `a` in order to let you call its member functions, e.g. `a.size()` or `a.c_str()`.

Comment: Thanks, having both the type and name looked like a redeclaration to me which confused me.

Comment: @Hobbyist You can declare the same thing as many times as you wish, as long as all declarations are consistent with each other. In fact, in C++ a definition is not only a definition, but a combined definition/declaration. It is defining that should generally be done only once to avoid linking errors.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way: The compiler sees A.cpp once, and only once.  If your project has many source files that #included A.h, the compiler would see A.h multiple times, once for each #include, as it processes all the *.cpp files.  It is logical in that scenario that there be one definition, and multiple declarations

What you have is correct - a variable in global scope in A.cpp.  Being global and non-static, it has the potential to be used elsewhere.  In fact it is polluting the namespace if it is not used elsewhere.